# Cube mapping does not work correctly using OpenGL/GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, skybox

I have a strange behaviour with Cube Mapping technique: all my pixel shaders return the black color. So I have in result a black screen.

Here's the situation:

I have a scene only composed by a simple cube mesh (the skybox) and a track ball camera.

Now let's examine the resources (the aspect of the 6 separate textures):

[image]

Here's the image details :

[image]

So as you can see these textures need to be loaded in GL_RGB format.

Now, for the initialization part, let's take a look to the client C++ texture loading code (I use the 'DevIL' library to load my images):

```
glGenTextures(1, &this->m_Handle);
glBindTexture(this->m_Target, this->m_Handle);
{
    glTexParameteri(this->m_Target, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(this->m_Target, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(this->m_Target, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(this->m_Target, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(this->m_Target, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    {
        for (uint32_t idx = 0; idx < this->m_SourceFileList.size(); idx++)
        {
            ilLoadImage((const wchar_t*)this->m_SourceFileList[idx].c_str()); //IMAGE LOADING
            {
                uint32_t width = ilGetInteger(IL_IMAGE_WIDTH);
                uint32_t height = ilGetInteger(IL_IMAGE_HEIGHT);
                uint32_t bpp = ilGetInteger(IL_IMAGE_BPP);
                {
                    char *pPixelData = (char*)ilGetData();

                    glTexImage2D(this->m_TargetList[idx], 0, GL_RGB8,
                        width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pPixelData);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
glBindTexture(this->m_Target, 0);
```

Concerning the main loop part, here's the informations I send to the shader program (texture and matrix data):

```
//TEXTURE DATA

scene::type::MaterialPtr pSkyBoxMaterial = pBatch->GetMaterial();

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP,
    pSkyBoxMaterial->GetDiffuseTexture()->GetHandle());
this->SetUniform("CubeMapSampler", 1);

//MATRIX DATA

this->SetUniform("ModelViewProjMatrix", pBatch->GetModelViewProjMatrix());
```

As you can see the cube map texture in bound to texture unit 1.

Now here's the vertex shader:

```
#version 400

/*
** Vertex attributes.
*/
layout (location = 0) in vec3 VertexPosition;

/*
** Uniform matrix buffer.
*/
uniform mat4 ModelViewProjMatrix;

/*
** Outputs.
*/
out vec3 TexCoords;

/*
** Vertex shader entry point.
*/
void main(void)
{
    TexCoords = VertexPosition;

    gl_Position = ModelViewProjMatrix * vec4(VertexPosition, 1.0f);
}
```

And finally the fragment shader:

```
#version 400

/*
** Output color value.
*/
layout (location = 0) out vec4 FragColor;

/*
** Vertex inputs.
*/
in vec3 TexCoords;

/*
** Texture uniform.
*/
uniform samplerCube CubeMapSampler;

/*
** Fragment shader entry point.
*/
void main(void)
{
    vec4 finalColor = texture(CubeMapSampler, TexCoords);

    FragColor = finalColor;
}
```

So all the program compiled and executed show the following result :

[image]

But I want to precise I use the NVIDIA NSight Debugger and I want to show you first that the cube map is correctly loaded on the GPU:

[image]

As you can see as it's been written in the pieces of code above my texture is a RGB texture bound to unit texture 1 and it's a GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP texture type. So until here all seems to be correct!

And if I replace in the fragment shader the line:

```
vec4 finalColor = texture(CubeMapSampler, TexCoords);
```

By the line:

```
vec4 finalColor = vec4(TexCoords, 1.0f);
```

I have the following result (I render directly the vertex coordinates in model space as color) without wireframe:

[image]

And the same result with wireframe:

[image]

Plus I want to precise that the line:

```
std::cout << glGetError() << std::endl;
```

Always returns the '0' value so I have none error!

So I think these two last pictures show that the matrix informations are correct and the vertex cordinates are correct too (moreover I use a track ball camera and when I move around into my scene I can recognize the cube architecture). So for me all the informations I recover in my shader program are correct except for the cube sampler! I think the problem comes from this sampler. However as you could see above the cube map seems to be loaded correctly.

I am really lost in front of this situation. I don't understand why all the pixel shaders return a #000000 color (I also tried using RGBA format but the result is the same).

Comment: Are you setting the `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER` parameter on the texture?

Comment: Yes I've just updated my post. The MIN and MAG filter types are GL_LINEAR and my wrapping types are all equal to GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE. Plus I have no OpenGL error during the initialization and the main loop. It's very strange.

Comment: Thank you! You were right. I reset accidentally the MIN_FILTER  value initially GL_LINEAR to GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR and I didn't call the method glGenerateMipmap(this->m_Target). That's why the cube map color rendering didn't work. However I wonder why the  function 'glGetError' did not return an error for this! Thank you for your help! Bye.

Comment: @user1364743: It did not reprot an error because that is not an error condition.